# How to pass the id name to the jQuery validation and send to the controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

I have two anchor tag and on click, I have to get the id value.

so I tried below code and I am getting the id. Now after getting the id, I have to display the popup. so popup is also displaying.

```
<div class="buttonSet">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="sample1">Sample one</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="sample2">Sample two</a>
  </div>

    $(".buttonSet a").click(function() {
        alert(this.id);//getting the id name, just for an example
        $('#Popup').show();
    });
```

Popup code is

```
<div class="" id="Popup" style="display:none">
    <form action="" method="post" name="form1" id="form1" autocomplete="off">
      <div class="form-group ffl-wrapper">
        <label for="name" class="ffl-label">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group ffl-wrapper">
        <label for="email" class="ffl-label">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group ffl-wrapper">
        <label for="mobileno" class="ffl-label">Mobile Number</label>
        <input type="text" name="mobileno" class="form-control" id="mobileno">
      </div>


      <div class="form-group text-center btn_submit_action">
        <input type="submit" name="send" class="" value="Submit">
      </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Now I am confused how do I pass the id value to the jQuery validation and how to submit button will work. I mean I have one form and two buttons. The Same form will open on button click.  I have to get the information that which button is clicked and pass that button id to the jQuery validation and send to the form. Because I have to store the name of the button which is clicked.

jQuery validation

```
$("#form1").validate({
  rules: {
    name: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 3,
      lettersonly: true
    },
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    },
    mobileno: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 10,
      maxlength: 10,
      number: true
    }
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "//my url",
      type: "POST",
      data: $('#form1').serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        $("#Popup").hide();
        $("#popup_success").show();
      },
    }); // AJAX Get Jquery statment
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after getting the id you must add it to the form as a hidden input as follow

```
 $(".buttonSet a").click(function() {
        alert(this.id);//getting the id name, just for an example
        var id=$(this.id);
        $('#Popup #id').val(id);
        $('#Popup').show();
    });
```

for that you have to add a input element to the form

```
<div class="" id="Popup" style="display:none">
    <form action="" method="post" name="form1" id="form1" autocomplete="off">
     <input type="number" name="id" class="form-control" id="id">
      <div class="form-group ffl-wrapper">
        <label for="name" class="ffl-label">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group ffl-wrapper">
        <label for="email" class="ffl-label">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group ffl-wrapper">
        <label for="mobileno" class="ffl-label">Mobile Number</label>
        <input type="text" name="mobileno" class="form-control" id="mobileno">
      </div>


      <div class="form-group text-center btn_submit_action">
        <input type="submit" name="send" class="" value="Submit">
      </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

now it is time to add following rule your validation script

```
id: {
      required: true
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Give me some time to check.

Comment: I am not getting the id value in the form

Comment: I think,    $('#Popup #id').val(id); is not calling the id value to the popup

Comment: change the code to   $('#Popup').find("#id").val(id) and change type of inserted input to hidden

Comment: I think, there might be issue with  var id=$(this.id);.... is this $ sign is correct? I think I have to remove the $ sign

Comment: replace var id=$(this.id); with var id=$(this).attr("id");

Comment: Yes your last comment is working also if I remove $ sign from  $(this.id) then also it's working. I just want to know why you use $('#Popup #id')?

Comment: it is possible to select nested elements using jquery

Comment: So   $('#Popup #id') , #id is id in the form?

Comment: yes <input type="number" name="id" class="form-control" id="id">

Comment: Thanks for the information. Appreciate your help and support.

Comment: Rules within the `rules` object are only assigned by `name`, not `id`.